# How to make bash put prompt on a new line after cat command?

Tags: bash, osx, prompt, cat

What I get:

```
host:~ user$ cat example.txt
some texthost:~ stas$
```

What I want to get:

```
host:~ user$ cat example.txt
some text
host:~ stas$
```

Is there a way I can make `cat` behave like this?

I'm using bash on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Most unix tools are designed to work well with text files. A text file consists of a sequence of lines. A line consists of a sequence of printable characters ending with a newline character. In particular, the last character of a non-empty text file is always a newline character. Evidently, `example.txt` contains only `some text` with no final newline, so it is not a text file.

`cat` does a simple job; turning arbitrary files into text files isn't part of that job. Some other tools always turn their input into text files; if you aren't sure the file you're displaying ends with a newline, try running `awk 1` instead of `cat`.

You can make the bash display its prompt on the next line if the previous command left the cursor somewhere other than the last margin. Put this in your `.bashrc` (variation [by GetFree](https://serverfault.com/questions/97503/bash-how-to-know-if-the-last-commands-output-ends-with-a-newline-or-not) of a proposal [by Dennis Williamson](https://serverfault.com/questions/97503/bash-how-to-know-if-the-last-commands-output-ends-with-a-newline-or-not/97543#97543)):

```
shopt -s promptvars
PS1='$(printf "%$((COLUMNS-1))s\r")'$PS1
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for a working solution and succinct explanation!
I understand this is a bit much for poor `cat`, so I'll keep this as a last resort for the time when this issue starts bothering me again.

Comment: Since this is bash preference, can it break piping commands?

Comment: @StanislavShabalin This doesn't affect piping, only the prompt.

Comment: I need to remove the "-1" after "COLUMNS" for this to work correctly.

Comment: This solution causes the prompt to move when the terminal window is resized. I found that to make this work reliably I had to get the current column in `PROMPT_COMMAND` and, if it is not 0, use a newline (`\n`) as the first character of `PS1`.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Hmm, good point. You should post your code as a separate answer.

Comment: "In particular, the last character of a non-empty text file is always a newline character." From what textbook does this come from?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko ??? It doesn't come from a textbook.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' so is that your personal opinion or ???

Comment: @AntonDuzenko It's not an opinion, it's a factual statement. It's a consequence of the fact that a [text file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) consists of zero or more lines concatenated together, and a [line](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206) ends with a newline characters.

Answer (score 32):

I prefer the following method...

```
cat example.txt ; echo
```

This doesn't doesn't evaluate the contents of `example.txt` or occasionally add a newline.  It just echos a newline once the cat is done, is easy to remember, and no one is thinking about whether they're using strong or weak quoting correctly.

The only downside, really, is that you'll get an extra newline if the file has its own trailing newline.

Comment: Nice and this works fine.

Comment: The `echo` also masks the exit-status of `cat`, so that the final exit-status is that of `echo` rather than of `cat`. To avoid that, you could do `cat example.txt && echo`, to only execute `echo` if `cat` was successful.

Answer (score 7):

I started using @Gilles's answer, but found that if the terminal changed the number of columns the prompt would no longer be at the start of a line as expected. This can happen for a variety of reasons, including tmux/screen splits, manual resizing of a GUI container, font changes, etc.

What I really wanted was something that would add a newline if the terminal would start printing its prompt at something other than the first column. To do this I needed to figure out how to get the current column, which I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575525/549363) to get. The final working prompt configuration is below:

```
###
# Configure PS1 by using the old value but ensuring it starts on a new line.
###
__configure_prompt() {
  PS1=""

  if [ "$(__get_terminal_column)" != 0 ]; then
    PS1="\n"
  fi

  PS1+="$PS1_WITHOUT_PREPENDED_NEWLINE"
}

###
# Get the current terminal column value.
#
# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575525/549363.
###
__get_terminal_column() {
  exec < /dev/tty
  local oldstty=$(stty -g)
  stty raw -echo min 0
  echo -en "\033[6n" > /dev/tty
  local pos
  IFS=';' read -r -d R -a pos
  stty $oldstty
  echo "$((${pos[1]} - 1))"
}

# Save the current PS1 for later.
PS1_WITHOUT_PREPENDED_NEWLINE="$PS1"

# Use our prompt configuration function, preserving whatever existing
# PROMPT_COMMAND might be configured.
PROMPT_COMMAND="__configure_prompt;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: I use this solution, but when I try to paste multi-line commands into my shell, it seems to end up eating part/all of the lines after the first one pasted. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @onlynone possibly your commands are not flushed individually and in time for `__get_terminal_column` ?

Comment: Instead of `PS1="\n"` I just have `echo` and don't need to modify `PS1`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to prevent swallowing multi-line commands as mentioned by @onlynone above? I tried numerous variations of this from a the other linked options to no avail even with a simple prompt of only $ without any non-printing characters.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with that could be that your example.txt does not have a newline at the end of your file.

Comment: The thing is I don't care if the file has a newline at the end or not. I wanna be able to see cat output more clear and not this disruptive :-)
And I understand it's not `cat`'s job so probably I'm looking for some workaround.

Comment: This is such a non answer `example.txt` not having a new line at the end of the file is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using `cat`, this works for both types of files, with and without a newline at the end:

```
echo "`cat example.txt`"
```

You can turn it into a function with a name of your choice (even `cat`) in your `.bashrc`:

```
cat1(){ echo "`/bin/cat $@`";}
```

Comment: Now that's a bit too much, even if it works ;-) Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

you can add to .bashrc as well

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '\n';$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

works for me.

Comment: This would also add an _extra_ blank line in the terminal whenever a utility outputs something that is properly terminated by a newline.

Comment: That is true. But is simple, and if it does not bother you to have an extra line...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modern Bash + terminal, you can use [this solution](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/-/merge_requests/118/diffs) based on a few similar answers:

```bsh
# Get the "raw" form of the row and column
IFS=';' read -d R -p "$(tput u7)" -r -s row column

if [[ "$column" -ne 1 ]]
then
    # Remove cruft from row to get the integer value
    row="${row#*[}"

    # Decrement column to avoid adding an empty space before the EOT marker
    ((column--))

    # Add an inverted ␄ symbol and newline before the rest of $PS1
    PS1="$(tput cup "$row" "$column")$(tput rev)␄$(tput sgr0)\n${PS1}"
fi
```

Pros:

- Uses `tput` rather than escape sequences for easy searching and (probably?) wider support.
- Prints the Unicode [end-of-transmission character (EOT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character) character (I couldn't find a more appropriate EOF marker, if it exists) in inverted colours followed by a newline to indicate the missing newline at EOF. This has the advantage of being easy to spot, while being short (a single character). Outputting a newline before the rest of `$PS1` ensures that it's not clobbered by `$PS1` if that contains a carriage return character.
- Easy to change to use other formatting (colours, bold, etc) and another marker, if you want to.

Cons:

- Uses `tput` rather than escape sequences, so it might not work on older terminals.