# Edit a command?

Tags: shell, osx, command, cat

I'm using many basic commands of unix/linux. In Mac OS X Mavericks, I type cat for a file, but output was faulty.

In example, content of the file named bar:

```
foo   
bar
```

Then:

```
kaanklky-air:foo-folder kaanklky$ cat bar
foo
barkaanklky-air:foo-folder kaanklky$
```

`cat` command give last line of file with shell's last status, so I want edit `cat` command to fix it.

How I can do it?

Comment: @Ramesh sorry and thank you! This helped me: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60469/80962 . But still I want learn how to edit a shell command.

Comment: no issues. Welcome to U & L SE :) Glad that you got your issue resolved. Do not hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: @KaanKölköy - this will probably get closed as a duplicate.  Feel free to post a new question specifically about 'editing shell commands', but you'll need to be specific (and it might not be as easy as you want, depending on what command you're trying to change).