# How to insert some end-of-file marker when command output doesn't end with a newline?

Tags: bash

[This blog post](https://ianthehenry.com/posts/how-to-learn-nix/new-profiles/) mentions a neat trick where the shell prints some special output after any command output which doesn't end in a newline. This avoids messing with the prompt, and avoids having to re-run the command with something like `; echo ␄` at the end to see the last line, so I'd like to enable/implement it in my .bashrc. How would I do this?

Comment: Go zsh; had to chuckle when I saw *"In my shell these special backslashes render with reversed colors, so it’s obvious they aren’t part of the output, but my blog is not smart enough to be able to reproduce that."*

Comment: It would be easy enough to reproduce - thankfully, HTML doesn't use ANSI escape codes :D

Comment: If you can't use zsh, you could have your prompt *always* include a leading new line.

Comment: @muru I do want it to be conditional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make bash put prompt on a new line after cat command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60459/how-to-make-bash-put-prompt-on-a-new-line-after-cat-command) (though I rather like janos' variant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943482/configure-shell-to-always-print-prompt-on-new-line-like-zsh/20152662#20152662)).